# Need help to understand a line of a proof of diagonalizability of real symmetric matrices

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was reading a proof of diagonalizability of real symmetric matrices using the concept of generalized eigenvalues and understood all except the very starting (and fundamental) line of the proof " if a symmetric matrix is not diagonalizable then it must have generalized eigenvalues of order 2 or higher " , please explain , help me to understand , thank you .

Comment: Do you mean [generalized eigenvectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Generalized_eigenvectors)?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Generalized eigenvalues is also used http://control.ucsd.edu/mauricio/courses/mae280a/lecture11.pdf

Comment: I see, aren't they just the eigenvalues? Anyway, the line just says that *there is a nontrivial Jordan block for some eigenvalue*.

Comment: @mfl: yes yes , that's the exact document I read it from ; please explain

Answer (score 0):

A way of restating this: if a matrix $A$ is diagonalizable, then there is no vector $v$, scalar (eigenvalue) $\lambda$, and integer $n\geq2$ such that
$$
(A- \lambda I)v \neq 0 \text{ but } (A-\lambda I)^nv =0
$$

Comment: I do not know the statement you have made . Please include a proof

Comment: @SouvikDey As I've already told you, this is related to the occurence of a nontrivial Jordan block and in order to understand the statement in the answer, you need to understand the Jordan form. If a matrix is not diagonalizable it necessarily has a nontrivial (of the dimension higher than one) Jordan block associated with some eigenvalue $\lambda$ and a generalized eigenvector $v$ for which $(A-\lambda I)v\neq 0$ but $(A-\lambda I)^2v=0$. See the linked [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Generalized_eigenvectors).